# Julia convert NamedTuple to Dict

Tags: dictionary, type-conversion, julia, namedtuple

I would like to convert a `NamedTuple` to a `Dict` in Julia. Say I have the following `NamedTuple`:

```
julia> namedTuple = (a=1, b=2, c=3)
(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
```

I want the following:

```
julia> Dict(zip(keys(namedTuple), namedTuple))
Dict{Symbol, Int64} with 3 entries:
  :a => 1
  :b => 2
  :c => 3
```

This works, however I would've hoped for a somewhat simpler solution - something like

```
julia> Dict(namedTuple)
ERROR: ArgumentError: Dict(kv): kv needs to be an iterator of tuples or pairs
```

would have been nice. Is there such a solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way to get an iterator of keys and values for any key-value collection is [`pairs`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.pairs):

```
julia> Dict(pairs(namedTuple))
Dict{Symbol, Int64} with 3 entries:
  :a => 1
  :b => 2
  :c => 3
```