# Creating an unnamed object to serialize in JSON

Tags: json, dictionary, julia

My function will take a DataFrame and create a set of nested Dicts to represent a series of grants made.

```
function getgrants(Grantrows)
    if nrow(Grantrows)==0
        return nothing
    end
    Grants = Dict()
    let j = 0
        for GCSGrants in eachrow(Grantrows)
            j += 1
            Grants[j] = Dict(
                "GrantID" => GCSGrants.Grant_ID,
                "GrantDate" => GCSGrants.Grant_Date,
                "GrantAmount" => GCSGrants.Grant_Amount,
                "GrantTitle" => GCSGrants.Grant_Title,
                "GrantDistributor" => GCSGrants.Grant_Distributor,
            )
        end
    end
    return Grants
end
```

`Grants` itself is nested into a larger hierarchy of Dicts which I ultimately use to create a json file.
The grants are serialized as

```
"Grants": {
   "1": {
       "GrantTitle": "Recipient 1",
       "GrantDate": "2022-03-16",
       "GrantAmount": 600000,
       "GrantDistributor": "Distributor 1",
       "GrantID": "ID789"
   },
   "2": {
       "GrantTitle": "Recipient 2",
       "GrantDate": "2020-09-02",
       "GrantAmount": 250000,
       "GrantDistributor": "Distributor 2",
       "GrantID": "ID456"
   },
   "3": {
       "GrantTitle": "Recipient 3",
       "GrantDate": "2020-06-25",
       "GrantAmount": 448770,
       "GrantDistributor": "Distributor 3",
       "GrantID": "ID123"
   }
}
```

The enumeration of the grants is unnecessary. I'd like to just use a series of unnamed objects. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Instead of enumeration, `using Random; randstring(16)` generates a string which would hardly repeat in the dataset (though this may not be good enough).

Comment: Another option would be to use the `GrantID` instead of the enumeration. This probably conforms to it being a unique key in the source database (but I'm not sure if this unnamed key issue is important... perhaps using a relational DB instead of JSON is a better idea).

Comment: Thank you for these suggestions, Dan. However, what I really want is for the inner objects not to be named at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want a [JSON array](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259.html#section-5) of [objects](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259.html#section-4) rather than an object of objects. To do that, make `Grants` in your example a `Vector{Dict}` rather than a `Dict{Dict}`. This simplified example dynamically builds the output vector by row:

```
using DataFrames

function to_array_of_obj(df)
    output = Vector{Dict}()
    for row in eachrow(df)
        # you can filter out whatever keys you want for your needs here;
        # this just takes them all
        push!(output, Dict(names(row) .=> values(row))
    end
    return output
end

data = DataFrame(A=[1,2,3], B=["x", "y", "z"])

to_array_of_obj(data)
# 3-element Vector{Dict}:
#  Dict{String, Any}("B" => "x", "A" => 1)
#  Dict{String, Any}("B" => "y", "A" => 2)
#  Dict{String, Any}("B" => "z", "A" => 3)
```

The output of this function will serialize into a JSON array of objects. For example, using [JSON3.jl](https://quinnj.github.io/JSON3.jl/stable/):

```
using JSON3

JSON3.pretty(to_array_of_obj(data))
# [
#     {
#         "B": "x",
#         "A": 1
#     },
#     {
#         "B": "y",
#         "A": 2
#     },
#     {
#         "B": "z",
#         "A": 3
#     }
# ]
```

If you don't mind Dicts with Symbols as keys instead of Strings, you can write everything in a one-liner, making use of the fact that `eachrow(df)` iterates as NamedTuple objects, and building Dicts from NamedTuples following [the answer to another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69756319/5075720):

```
to_array_of_obj2(df) = map(row -> Dict(pairs(row)), eachrow(df))

to_array_of_obj2(df)
# 3-element Vector{Dict{Symbol, Any}}:
#  Dict(:A => 1, :B => "x")
#  Dict(:A => 2, :B => "y")
#  Dict(:A => 3, :B => "z")
```

JSON3 will serialize this the same as the above example.

Comment: For practical purposes this is exactly what I want - thank you.

Comment: Going back again to the json specification, I can see that objects must contain name => value pairs. This means my original aspiration is not a legal json structure. If an object contains other objects, each of the inner objects must be named. This seems to be the primary difference between an object and an array in the json specification.